# React - Convertir componente a un svg

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

Estoy utilizando react para crear un componente que renderiza un svg, he decidido crearlo como componente para poder manipular sus colores.

```
import React from 'react';
const Home = ({ color}) => (
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <rect fill="none" className="a" width="30" height="30"/>
  <path fill={color} lass="b" d="M20.865,443.084l-8.482-8.362-.569-.561a.7.7,0,0,0-.975,0l-9.051,8.923a1.384,1.384,0,0,0-.309.457,1.364,1.364,0,0,0-.1.539A1.41,1.41,0,0,0,2.8,445.451h.933V452.5H18.92v-7.053h.953a1.407,1.407,0,0,0,.994-.407,1.372,1.372,0,0,0,0-1.96Zm-8.309,7.86H10.1v-4.417h2.459Zm4.783-7.053v7.053H13.961v-4.937a.872.872,0,0,0-.878-.866H9.571a.872.872,0,0,0-.878.866v4.937H5.314v-7.053H3.207l8.122-8,.507.5,7.613,7.5Z" transform="translate(3.239 -428.194)"/>
</svg>
);

export default Home;
```

Mi problema ahora es que necesito utilizar ese componente en un `background-image`. Hay manera de poder exportar ese componente como svg con sus respectivas modificaciones de color asignadas.

Answer (score 1):

Directamente como background no ,ya que es un componente , exportarlo si que puedes y cambiarle los colores solo importas el componente donde lo necesitas

```
import React from "react";
const Svg = ({ color }) => (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="30"
    height="30"
    viewBox="0 0 30 30"
  >
    <rect fill="none" className="a" width="30" height="30" />
    <path
      fill={color}
      lass="b"
      d="M20.865,443.084l-8.482-8.362-.569-.561a.7.7,0,0,0-.975,0l-9.051,8.923a1.384,1.384,0,0,0-.309.457,1.364,1.364,0,0,0-.1.539A1.41,1.41,0,0,0,2.8,445.451h.933V452.5H18.92v-7.053h.953a1.407,1.407,0,0,0,.994-.407,1.372,1.372,0,0,0,0-1.96Zm-8.309,7.86H10.1v-4.417h2.459Zm4.783-7.053v7.053H13.961v-4.937a.872.872,0,0,0-.878-.866H9.571a.872.872,0,0,0-.878.866v4.937H5.314v-7.053H3.207l8.122-8,.507.5,7.613,7.5Z"
      transform="translate(3.239 -428.194)"
    />
  </svg>
);
const General = () => {
  return (
    <div className="someClassName" style={{ backgroundImage: Svg }}>
      <Svg color="red" />
    </div>
  );
};
export default General;
```

Comment: Si comprendo que esa es la solución, si lo que quisiera renderizar fuera un componente. Pero necesito las propiedades de css como `backgroud-repeat` entre otras.